# Panel regression without predictors in R

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, panel-data, plm

I want to run a `plm` regression model **without predictors** (i.e. a regression model on the intercept).

When I run a *fixed effects* model (`"within"`) I get the error message "empty model" below:

```
feModel <- plm(outcome ~ 1, data = DT, model = "within", index = c("ID", "year"))

# Error in plm.fit(data, model, effect, random.method, random.models, random.dfcor,  : 
  empty model
```

This also happens for `model = "random"` and `"between"` models.

However, when I run a *pooled OLS* model (`"pooling"`), the code runs okay.

Can someone explain why this works just for the pooled model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the between model, it is a bug that is fixed in the development version 2.4-1.999999 of the package (https://r-forge.r-project.org/R/?group_id=406), from the NEWS file:
"between.matrix: do not coerce result to numeric vector for n x 1 matrix input (use drop = FALSE in extraction) (prior to this fix, estimation of the between model with only an intercept errored)." Follwing the installation instructions from the development platform to install the development version and running the between model will work:

```
# needed to install the latest development version:
# install.packages("plm", repos="http://R-Forge.R-project.org") 
be <- plm(outcome ~ 1, data = DT, model = "between", index = c("ID", "year"))
```

The point estimate for the intercept is the mean of the dependend variable (as it would be for a pooling model (`plm(outcome ~ 1, data = DT, model = "pooling", index = c("ID", "year"))`).

For the random effects model a la Swamy-Arora: This is a statistical question. This specific model employs weighting of the corresponding within and between models. As the within model with only an intercept is not estimable by software packages which do not estimate within models with an intercept (it degenerates to a pooled model, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68430329/4640346), the random effect model estimations which use a within model fail as well.

You can use other random effect estimators which do not use a within model as part of their estimation technique like the Wallace-Hussain estimator (see an overview of the implemented RE estimators and the basic models they use to derive variance estimations in plm's 2nd vignette: https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/plm/vignettes/B_plmFunction.html). So, this will work:

```
re_walhus <- plm(outcome ~ 1, data = DT, model = "random", random.method = "walhus", index = c("ID", "year"))
```

As the Wallace-Hussain estimator employs the pooling model, the point estimate for the intercept is the mean of the dependend variable (just like for the between and the pooling model).